# TransformError when running React Native Getting Started project (iOS)

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm having trouble getting the React Native Getting Started project to run.

I followed this guide: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html

When I try to run the project from Xcode, the packager gets to " transform" then an error appears in the simulator.

TransformError: Projects/AwesomeProject/node_modules/react-native/packager/react-packager/src/DependencyResolver/polyfills/prelude_dev.js: Unknown plugin "node-env-inline"

Here are my versions:

```
OS X Yosemite 10.10.1
Node 4.2.1
Xcode 6.4
React Native 0.12.0
```

Comment: Having this problem myself, the answer below doesn't fix it for me :(

Answer (score 2):

Had this same problem.  I had a `~/.babelrc` that was mucking everything up.  I tried everything I could find

1. `rm -rf node_modules`
2. `npm cache clean`
3. changed versions of node
4. `npm install`

Finally... the solution for me was:

`sudo lsof -n -i4TCP:8081` 
then kill the process and rerun `react-native run-ios`

Answer (score 1):

Delete `node_modules` directory, running `npm cache clean`, then `npm i` again. And you have to restart the packager.

Comment: just restarting was enough for me

Answer (score 0):

Go to your root folder in command line

```
cd appName
```

Now you have to run the packager

```
react-native start
```

or

```
npm start
```

Run the app on the simulator

**Android**

```
react-native run-android
```

**iOS**

```
react-native run-ios
```

you should keep this terminal open running while developing your app

Answer (score 0):

It is caused by bug in babel-preset-react-native.
Although solutions already provided here reinstall modules, package.json is still pointing to 3.0 of babel-preset-react-native and doesn't help you.

To solve this problem, I think you need to update package.json to point babel-preset-react-native to 2.1.

```
"dependencies": {
"react": "16.0.0-alpha.12",
"react-native": "0.47.1",
"babel-preset-react-native": "2.1.0"
},
```

See above, now babel-preset-react-native points to 2.1.0.
Then,

```
rm -rf node_module
npm cache clean
npm i
```

And restart whichever android or ios.
At least, this worked for me.