# react-native 0.1.5 TransformError: /path_to_app/index.ios.js Unknown plugin "node-env-inline"

Tags: react-native

I've just updated both **watchman**, **homebrew** and **react-native-cli**

The result is that all my new as well as old react-native applicationsare giving the same error.

It is a  *TransformError in index.ios.js*

[this is what i got in the simulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CCSX8.png)

I looked into this question: 
[TransformError when running React Native Getting Started project (iOS)]

([TransformError when running React Native Getting Started project (iOS)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33141978/transformerror-when-running-react-native-getting-started-project-ios))

But, the answer did not worked for me.

i did :

*rm -rf node_modules*

*npm cache clean*

*npm i*

*npm start*

and it did not work.

Does any one know what is happening?

Comment: Having this problem myself :( didn't you come up with a solution?

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this issue as well. It appears to be a missing babel plugin. Run `npm install babel-plugin-node-env-inline` to fix. I also had to install `babel-plugin-dunderscore-dev-inline`.